# Принудительное завершение фонового потока с произвольной синхронной функцией

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Добрый день!
Задача состоит в том, чтобы создать дерево в узлах которого будет запускаться тестируемая функция и если она не отработала за отведенное время - принудительно завершать исполнение. Т.к. тестируемых функций планируется много, то на мой взгляд, надо использовать либо делегаты либо ссылки на функции, которые описать где-нибудь в одном месте отдельно. Важно чтобы из потока можно было вернуть результат его выполнения или исключение.

```
public class TesterNode
{
    //ссылка на тестируемую функцию
    private Func<TestResult> TestFunc;
    private TestResult state = TestResult.NotRunning;

    public TestResult RunAction()
    {
        if (TestFunc != null)
        {
            state = TestResult.Running;

            //этот метод должен выполнять тестируемую функцию 
            //и если та не отработала за определенный промежуток времени
            //возвращать TestResult.Timeout
            var res = TestFuncAsync();
            if (res == TestResult.Success || res == TestResult.Warning)
            {
                foreach (var item in childs)
                {
                    item.RunAction();
                }
            }
            return res;
        }
        else
            return TestResult.Error;
    }
}
```

Comment: А в чем, собственно, проблема?

Comment: Не могу правильно написать TestFuncAsync. Пробовал через async/await но там есть только токен отмены операции, чтобы поток сам произвольно завершился, но это не приемлемый вариант, т.к. TestFunc использует внешний ресурс, который может зависнуть. Как сделать это через делегат - ума не приложу. А если использовать ссылку на функцию, то нужно писать что-то типа private Func<шт object, out void> TestFunc что является ошибкой синтаксиса. Вот и сижу, понять не могу как правильно это написать.

Comment: Вы же сами написали: завершить *поток*. А для того чтобы его завершить - надо сначала его создать!

Comment: Да, создать поток проблема:

Comment: Пишу с телефона, код не приведу. Но посмотрите класс Thread - там есть все что вам надо.

Comment: Да, создать поток проблема: Thread th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(TestFunc)); но создать его нельзя, т.к. TestFunc возвращает не void. А если писать описание функции типа  Func<in object, out void> TestFunc - тоже ошибка: недопустимые типы в шаблоне.

Comment: `Action<T>` - это `Func` который ничего не возвращает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте замыкания. Адаптировать функцию под другой прототип - не так сложно как кажется.

```
public delegate TestResult TestFunction();
public static TestResult TestWithTimeout(TestFunction func, TimeSpan timeout)
{
     TestResult result = TestResult.Timeout;
     var thread = new Thread(() => {
       try {
         result = func();
       }
       catch (ThreadAbortException) {}
       catch {
         result = TestResult.Error;
       }
     });
     thread.Start();
     if (!thread.Join(timeout))
       thread.Abort();

     return result;
}
```

Comment: Ну... Вам стоит написать всё же, что `Thread.Abort` — это **крайне** плохая идея, так как может разрушить состояние практически любого глобального объекта. (Особенно если код висит во «внешней» функции.)

Comment: @VladD ну, вы уже написали об этом :) Конкретно же в данном случае - по-другому сделать и не получится.